# Is there any way to avoid challenging all registered authentication schemes when one of them succeeds?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am facing an issue related to handling multiple authentication schemes in an asp.net core application which exposes API.
In particular, I am attempting to make two different authentication modes available, by registering two *schemes*, each with its own *handler*.
At the moment my configuration code (simplified) looks like this:

```cs
public class Startup {
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services
      .AddAuthentication()
      .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthHandler>("Basic", o => {});
      .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiKeyAuthHandler>("ApiKey", o => {});

    services.AddAuthorization(o => {
      o.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Basic", "ApiKey").Build();
    });
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
  }
}

public class BasicAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> {
  protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() { 
   Console.WriteLine("Challenging Basic Authentication");
     if( ... ) {
       return AuthenticateResult.Success(...);
     }
     return AuthenticateResult.Fail(...);
  }  
}

public class ApiKeyAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> {
  protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() { 
   Console.WriteLine("Challenging ApiKey Authentication");
     if( ... ) {
       return AuthenticateResult.Success(...);
     }
     return AuthenticateResult.Fail(...);
  }  
}
```

The `ApiKeyAuthHandler` authenticates requests depending on a custom header (say `X-ApiKey`) value, the `BasicAuthHandler` authenticates requests depending on credentials provided through `Authorization: Basic BASE_ENCODED_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD` header.

Both handlers work fine: I can provide `Authorization` header with *basic auth* credentials and I can provide an *api-key* through the custom header.
Generally speaking, the two registered handlers are executed sequentially, in the same order I've registered them. So far, so good.

However, when I provide **both** basic credentials in `Authorization` header **and** *api-key* through `X-ApiKey` header, I noticed that

- the first handler (`BasicAuthHandler`) is executed, returning `AuthenticateResult.Success`
- the second handler (`ApiKeyAuthHandler`) is executed, **even the first already authenticated the request successfylly**, also returning `AuthenticateResult.Success`
- the identity finally available in my controller is the one built by the second handler

I'm wondering why the second handler is executed after the first completed authentication successfully: I googled about this but can't found any configuration flags to enable a sort of *short-circuit* after the first *success* result.

The reason seems to be [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/26d27d871b7992022c082dc207e3d126e1d9d278/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L38) `foreach` *statement* that iterates over all available authentication *schemes* regardless of theirs results.

Does anyone have any idea of a way to challenge available authentication *scheme* while no one is successful, stopping when the first succeeds?
No doubt I could implement a `CompositeAuthHandler` in order to manage this requirement, but I would prefer an already-made, *official* solution to my problem.

A note about the context which justifies the requirement of short-circuit handler evaluation: the example provided above is simplified and uses two very cheap authentication handlers, but the real case I'm facing off involves at least one very slow handler, that perform *paid* calls to an external system - so I would like to avoid calling it for requests already authenticated by former handlers.

Comment: You mean that you now have two authentication schemes. As long as the user successfully performs one of the verifications, the second one does not need to continue to verify the identity, right?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my desired behaviour!

Comment: @Pietro Martinelli Did you find a solution to our question? If so, could you please post it as I am trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Sandy, no, i didn't found any solution: in my original use case I simply accepted that all schemes are challenged...

Comment: @PietroMartinelli I am facing same issue. I have one Auth scheme by Username/Password http headers while another one basic authentication. I explicitly defined Policy and Authentication Scheme in Authorize Attribute, but still both are being called sequentially.